# Find the values that satisfy certain limit equality

Tags: calculus, limits

i have to find the values: $$ a,b $$ that satisfy this equality:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{a\,x+b}−3}{x}=1 $$

my aproach is by doing L'Hôpital:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}  \frac{a}{2\,\sqrt{a\,x+b}}=1$$

so this means $$ a=1, b=1/4 $$

or i should make notice that "b" depends of the values that "a" can take?

Comment: You can't blindly use L'hôpital. You first need to check if the limit is undetermined.

Comment: but 0/0 is not an indetermination?

Comment: But in order to have $0/0$ you have to have that $\sqrt{ax+b}-3=0$,which doesn't happen when $b=1/4$ but when $b=9$.If $b=1/4$ than limit of $\sqrt{ax+1/4}-3=1/2-3=-5/2$.

Comment: @user137201 It is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the expression at the top of the fraction to go to $0$ as $x\to0$, in order to use L'Hôpital. So you want $a0+b=b=9$. Then do like you did and you will find $a=6$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{ax+b}-3=0\Longrightarrow b=9$$